Divergence theorem on manifolds without boundary.
Consider a manifold $(M,g)$ and a vector field $X$. The divergence theorem reads
$$\int_{M} \! dV \, \nabla_{\mu} X^{\mu} \enspace = \enspace \oint_{\partial M} \! dS \, n_{\mu} X^{\mu}$$
with $dV$ being the volume form on $M$ and $dS$ being the induced volume form on $\partial M$. This theorem is ok if $M$ is a manifold with boundary. However, if $M$ has no boundary (e.g. the open ball $B_R(0) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, g(x,0) < R\}$ what happens to the RHS?
I suppose I does not (!) just vanish by default due to the boundary being empty, as for e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a radial and constant vector field $X = \hat{e}_r$:
$$\int_{M} \! dV \, \nabla_{\mu} X^{\mu} \enspace = \enspace 4\pi \int_0^R \! dr \, 2r \enspace = \enspace 4\pi R^2$$
and so one would have $4\pi R^2 = 0$ which is of course wrong.

My motivation for asking this is that in field theory, the equations of motion are determined by variation of the so-called action functional. Wikipedia states these lines of equations (see picture). The condition that the field has to vanish on the boundary is given, but in general a spacetime does not have a boundary e.g. Minkowski spacetime. Yet the equations of motion are still derived this way. So what happens to the divergence-like term on manifolds that have no boundaries (e.g. compact and boundaryless, open and boundaryless, ...)

Note: Although it is physics related, I assume the question is rather suited for mathstackexchange as its main goal is to understand the divergence theorem rather than the assumption made within the action-formalism.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Formula, 06.08.2024

You forgot to assume compactness of $M$ or compact support of your vector field.

Well, but thats the point of the question. What happens when $M$ is not compact as it happens in field theory oftentimes (eg Minkowski spacetime)

Well, the theorem is false then and what you said in the 2nd sentence is wrong.
